# Javascript image manipulation? Pixel by pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

Is there a way or a library to obtain an images color data pixel by pixel in javascript?
I need to read lots of OMR form, and i want to do it on clients not on my server :D. So either i can build it the system with javascript if i can reach raw data or i have to build a desktop application which i don't like at all.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041399/how-to-use-javascript-or-jquery-to-read-a-pixel-of-an-image

Comment: i did it in silverlight a few months ago, and i don't believe that anything is impossible as long as i can get the user select images i want to read. Even reading the data byte by byte can be a solution(i did it this way in silverlight). So i just need what to use to reduce development time :D

Comment: @denisk, possible duplicate, but i also need any ideas that might help me achieve the goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 Canvas element is the way to go if you don't have browser limitations.

Comment: so i think canvas is the way to go, as long as i don't even support ie9 :D

Comment: Lucky you. I sometimes wish I could develop a web based app that doesn't need to support _any_ ie :)

Answer (score 15):

Sure, no need to use libraries. It's really simple through **canvases**.

`img  ->  canvas  ->  magic  ->  canvas  ->  img`

What you need is to:

1. create `<canvas>`
2. get canvas `context`
3. copy `img` to `canvas`
4. get canvas `image data` (an array of values `[r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,..]`)
5. **do `The magic`®**
6. put `image data` back
7. put changed `canvas` back to `<img>`

## the code to deal with canvas

```
var cvs = document.createElement('canvas'),
    img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];   // your image goes here
    // img = $('#yourImage')[0];                     // can use jquery for selection
cvs.width = img.width; cvs.height = img.height;
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);
var idt = ctx.getImageData(0,0,cvs.width,cvs.height);

// usage
getPixel(idt, 852);  // returns array [red, green, blue, alpha]
getPixelXY(idt, 1,1); // same pixel using x,y

setPixelXY(idt, 1,1, 0,0,0,255); // a black pixel
```

#### 6,7, modify the image ...

```
ctx.putImageData(idt, 0,0);  // 0,0 is xy coordinates
img.src = cvs.toDataURL();
```

#### wondered where the canvas is?

```
document.body.appendChild(cvs);
```

## some magic functions

Since the `image data` are an array of consecutive `r,g,b,a,r,g,..` values and one pixel consists of 4 values, you need to recalculate indexes. The formula is simple: `data[(y*width + x)*4 + ch]`, where `ch` is between `0` and `3` for `r,g,b,a` channels.

<sub>*Note that there is more concise and also **faster** solution below.*</sub>

```
function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  var i = index*4, d = imgData.data;
  return [d[i],d[i+1],d[i+2],d[i+3]] // [R,G,B,A]
}

function getPixelXY(imgData, x, y) {
  return getPixel(imgData, y*imgData.width+x);
}

function setPixel(imgData, index, r, g, b, a) {
  var i = index*4, d = imgData.data;
  d[i]   = r;
  d[i+1] = g;
  d[i+2] = b;
  d[i+3] = a;
}

function setPixelXY(imgData, x, y, r, g, b, a) {
  return setPixel(imgData, y*imgData.width+x, r, g, b, a);
}
```

---

## update 2019 `Uint8ClampedArray`

You can manipulate pixel data directly with this [subarray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) *"view"*.
`subarray` is different from `slice` or from previous example in that it does not create a shallow copy of the array but an array that shares the same store.

Read more at [MDN:Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray).

```
function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  return imgData.data.subarray(index*4, index*4+4) // Uint8ClampedArray(4) [R,G,B,A]
}

let px = getPixelXY(idt, 0, 0)
px[0] = 255

// ctx.putImageData(idt,0,0); // makes the pixel reddish
```

or

```
function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  return imgData.data.slice(index*4, index*4+4) // [R,G,B,A]
}

function setPixel(imgData, index, pixelData /*[R,G,B,A]*/) {
  imgData.data.set(pixelData, index*4)
}
```

Comment: Should definetely be the accepted answer! Thank you for such a piece of documentation

Answer (score 3):

I found this library which seems interesting : http://www.pixastic.com/

It can make a [color histogram](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/colorhistogram/) of your picture so I guess If you inspect the code a bit ..
But It doesn't seems to work with IE ..

I guess this part is interesting for you :

```
var ctx = params.canvas.getContext("2d");
var rect = params.options.rect;
var dataDesc = ctx.getImageData(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height);
var data = dataDesc.data;
if (!getCopy) params.canvasData = dataDesc;
  return data;
```

from pixtastic.core.js `prepareData` function

You can also find interesting info here : [What is leaking memory with this use of getImageData, javascript, HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892265/what-is-leaking-memory-with-this-use-of-getimagedata-javascript-html5-canvas)

Comment: i looked at it's code yesterday and it basically makes manipulation in a canvas, so if there is no other way, i am going to go for it

Comment: so i think canvas is the way to go, as long as i don't even support ie9 :D thank you man, but i coudn't select your answer because MeLight answered earler