# How to use html canvas toDataURL on IOS without increasing memory?

Tags: ios, html, memory-leaks, html5-canvas

Firstly, the following thread discusses the issue that toDataURL may increase memory consumption, but doesn't offer a way to use toDataURL safely:
[javascript memory leak with HTML5 getImageData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638007/javascript-memory-leak-with-html5-getimagedata/7971648#7971648)

In my application, I need to call toDataURL. I have a PhoneGap application running on IOS that take photos using the native camera, tiles the images together into one collage image, and sends the final image as a binary 64 string via ajax post to a server. The part of my code that tiles the images uses an html canvas and toDataURL to accomplish that. This tiling occurs repeatedly over the lifetime of the software process. I am seeing the application memory increase until IOS aborts the process.

What would you recommend to do to be able to call toDataURL but not run out of memory? I don't see how to release this memory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to memory manage, it may just be easier to send the independent images to the server and let the server create the collage for you.